# Bootstrap table spacing and styling

Tags: bootstrap-4, styling

I am currently learning bootstrap and I just came across this basic table. Can somebody explain to me what the lines that are surrounded by asterisks mean? does that have something to do with the spacing of a table?  I have been looking over the docs and I am still struggling to understand it, no matter how basic it seams.  Any explanation is appreciated.

```
    <div class="report-card-ii">
            **<div class="font-24 m-l-35 p-t-25 p-b-10">Carrier Snapshot</div>**
            **<div class="m-l-15 m-r-15">****
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="black-cell">
                            <th class="font-light">Name <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></th>
                            <th class="font-light">Twitter Handle</th>
                            <th class="font-light">Location</th>
                            <th class="font-light">email</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick Explanation (Code also corrected for BootStrap notation guide).

```
<div class="font-24 ml-35 pt-25 pb-10">Carrier Snapshot</div>
```

Font Size is 24
Margin Left is 35
Padding Top is 25
Padding Bottom is 10

```
<div class="ml-15 mr-15">
```

Margin Left is 15
Margin Right is 15

Reference:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/

Comment: I think spacing has no "- " between m and l. I mean margin left should be demonstrated as ml-3.

Comment: Good catch. Just quickly skimmed on the code he wrote.